# Is there a reason why duplicating this function causes it to run faster?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a spinner with CSS and JavaScript, to display while a page loads. 

I followed a CSS-Tricks tutorial for the basics and built up on it to make it better and work for my purposes. Everything works great, except that each time you create a spinner, it runs faster. I have demonstrated this with a `setTimeout` function to create a spinner three times. It is a little bit annoying, since it means I can only have one spinner per page load, and I cannot figure out how to get it to work without speeding up and doing this. Here is the code snippet: 
NOTE: Only works in Chrome :( sorry

```js
let a = (a)=>document.querySelector(a)
  , b = (a)=>document.querySelectorAll(a)
  , c = (a)=>document.getElementsByClassName(a)
  , d = (a)=>document.getElementById(a)
  , e = (a)=>document.getElementsByTagName(a)
  , f = document
  , k = function(i, j, k) {
    if (a('#c')) {
        a('#c').remove();
        z_zZ = 0;
    }
    let x = f.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg')
      , y = f.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    x.setAttribute('class', 'ak');
    x.id = 'c';
    x.setAttribute('width', i);
    x.setAttribute('height', i);
    y.setAttribute('class', 'ad ae aj');
    y.id = 'a';
    y.setAttribute('stroke', k);
    y.setAttribute('stroke-width', j);
    l(y, i, j);
    x.appendChild(y);
    y = f.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    y.setAttribute('class', 'ad ae aj');
    y.id = 'b';
    y.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
    y.setAttribute('stroke-width', j * 2);
    l(y, i, j);
    x.appendChild(y);
    return x;
}
  , l = function(i, j, k) {
    i.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    i.setAttribute('r', j / 2 - k / 2);
    i.setAttribute('cx', j / 2);
    i.setAttribute('cy', j / 2);
}
  , m = function() {
    let j = a('#a')
      , k = parseInt(j.getAttribute('r'))
      , l = k * 2 * Math.PI
      , m = a('#b');
    j.style.strokeDasharray = `${l} ${l}`;
    m.style.strokeDasharray = `${l} ${l}`;
    j.style.strokeDashoffset = l;
    m.style.strokeDashoffset = l;
    m.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
    let n = m;
    m.remove();
    function o(p) {
        let q = l - p / 100 * l;
        j.style.strokeDashoffset = q;
        m ? m.style.strokeDashoffset = q : null;
    }
    function q() {
        o(z_zZ);
        z_zZ++;
    }
    let r = setInterval(q, 20);
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(r);
        a('#c').appendChild(n);
        setInterval(q, 20);
    }, 200);
}
  , n = function(i, j, n, z) {
    i.appendChild(k(j, n, z));
    setTimeout(m(), 100);
}
  , z_zZ = 0;
n(a('body'), 50, 5, 'black');
setTimeout(function() { n(a('body'), 50, 5, 'orange') }, 5000);
setTimeout(function() { n(a('body'), 50, 5, 'red') }, 10000);
```

```css
.aj {z-index: 1;}
.ae {transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
.ad {transform: rotate(-90deg);}
.ak {animation: spinner 2s ease-in-out infinite;}
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you'll see, it works and shows a spinner, however for some reason it speeds up when it gets created a second time, and even more a third time. I am totally stumped as to what is going on here. Please help if you have any idea as to what is going wrong with this code which causes it to run faster on a second and subsequent creations.

Comment: That code is minified and unminified, why?

Comment: what do you mean by that? I just wanted to get rid of long variable names so I made them all one letter

Comment: That makes it unreadable.

Comment: ok... apologies. I will make it readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as you run the function `n` again, the function `m` inside it creates a new interval. Therefore now, there is 2 intervals running function `q` inside function `m`.

When 2 intervals run the same function, it means the function will be run 2 times.

In your case, `z_zZ` is being incremented twice as fast now. Hence your rotation doubles its speed.

What you need to do is add a variable `T` to store an interval instance. Then, clear the interval before you start a new interval.

See below for example. Modified lines are marked with `/* MODIFIED */`:

```js
let a = (a)=>document.querySelector(a)
  , b = (a)=>document.querySelectorAll(a)
  , c = (a)=>document.getElementsByClassName(a)
  , d = (a)=>document.getElementById(a)
  , e = (a)=>document.getElementsByTagName(a)
  , f = document
  , k = function(i, j, k) {
    if (a('#c')) {
        a('#c').remove();
        z_zZ = 0;
    }
    let x = f.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg')
      , y = f.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    x.setAttribute('class', 'ak');
    x.id = 'c';
    x.setAttribute('width', i);
    x.setAttribute('height', i);
    y.setAttribute('class', 'ad ae aj');
    y.id = 'a';
    y.setAttribute('stroke', k);
    y.setAttribute('stroke-width', j);
    l(y, i, j);
    x.appendChild(y);
    y = f.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    y.setAttribute('class', 'ad ae aj');
    y.id = 'b';
    y.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
    y.setAttribute('stroke-width', j * 2);
    l(y, i, j);
    x.appendChild(y);
    return x;
}
  , l = function(i, j, k) {
    i.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    i.setAttribute('r', j / 2 - k / 2);
    i.setAttribute('cx', j / 2);
    i.setAttribute('cy', j / 2);
}
  , m = function() {
    let j = a('#a')
      , k = parseInt(j.getAttribute('r'))
      , l = k * 2 * Math.PI
      , m = a('#b');
    j.style.strokeDasharray = `${l} ${l}`;
    m.style.strokeDasharray = `${l} ${l}`;
    j.style.strokeDashoffset = l;
    m.style.strokeDashoffset = l;
    m.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
    let n = m;
    m.remove();
    function o(p) {
        let q = l - p / 100 * l;
        j.style.strokeDashoffset = q;
        m ? m.style.strokeDashoffset = q : null;
    }
    function q() {
        o(z_zZ);
        z_zZ++;
    }
    let r = setInterval(q, 20);
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(r);
        a('#c').appendChild(n);
        clearInterval(T); /* MODIFIED */
        T = setInterval(q, 20); /* MODIFIED */
    }, 200);
}
  , T = null /* MODIFIED */
  , n = function(i, j, n, z) {
    i.appendChild(k(j, n, z));
    setTimeout(m(), 100);
}
  , z_zZ = 0;
n(a('body'), 50, 5, 'black');
setTimeout(function() { n(a('body'), 50, 5, 'orange') }, 5000);
setTimeout(function() { n(a('body'), 50, 5, 'red') }, 10000);
```

```css
.aj {z-index: 1;}
.ae {transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
.ad {transform: rotate(-90deg);}
.ak {animation: spinner 2s ease-in-out infinite;}
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS:

You shouldn't get rid of long variable names unless the one-letter name is meaningful. It makes us incredibly hard to understand your code, hence makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should've figured that but it makes sense.